# Why is the gas fee shown on Ether scan is different than the transaction I sent?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, sepolia

I sent a transaction to `Ethereum` test network `sepolia` as below code:

```
const transaction = {
            from: account.address,
            to: contractAddress,
            gas: 202419,
            gasPrice: 1083665,
            nonce: await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address),
            data: await contract.methods
              .createSector()
              .encodeABI(),
          };
          const singedTrnasaction = await w.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, privateKey);
          const response = await w.eth.sendSignedTransaction(singedTrnasaction.rawTransaction);
          console.log('send transaction response', response);
```

as you can see from above code, the gas I sent is `202419` and gas price is `1083665`.

```
202419 * 1083665 = 219354385635 Wei = 219.354385635 Gwei = 0.000000219354385635 Eth
```

but the transaction hash returned from above request is `0x2cc56ceb52aba065e8175161d46458fab94ca380f43d56d8187db853193cdcf2`. If you search this hash in https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x2cc56ceb52aba065e8175161d46458fab94ca380f43d56d8187db853193cdcf2, you will see the transaction fee is: `0.00000021484308824 eth`. You can see there is a small different between the two gas fee, `0.000000219354385635` and `0.00000021484308824`. Is it expected? Is there a maximum gap between the sent value and real value?

Answer (score 0):

Technically when you broadcast a transaction like that, your "gas" and "gasPrice" is what you are offering to miners to include this transaction into a the block. Or in other words the max amount of gas and price you are willing to spend.

If you offer less than the current gas price and the amount of gas required for calculation, your transaction may never get added to the blockchain.

If you offer more, then it's likely to be processed by a miner, but they may do it for lower gas price and spend less gas.